# How can I rename Page Layouts without having to manually reset content pages using those layouts?

Tags: publishing-site, master-page, page-layout, publishing-page

I need to rename a bunch of Page layouts and Master Pages without having to re-set the Page Layout to each content page that is using those layouts.

For example:

I have two page layouts - 'Home.aspx' and 'Home1.aspx' - and I want to rename them to something along the lines of 'project1_Home.aspx' and 'project2_Home.aspx'

I can do this fine in Sharepoint Designer but when I try to access a content page using one of the 'Home.aspx' or 'Home1.aspx' layouts I get a "The resource cannot be found." error page. The renaming hasn't taken affect.

I then have to manually go into the Page Settings an re-set the pages in question to access the project1_Home.aspx or project2_Home.aspx layouts.

Can I achieve this programmatically?

I have dozens of page layouts I want to rename (and perhaps move to subfolders) and hundreds of content pages use those layouts so it would take forever manually ! :)

Thanks,
del

Answer (score 1):

You can also run a simple powershell command that will allow you to change multiple page layouts all at once.  This is extremely helpful when doing a product version update.

Here is a sample of the powershell script: 
SP-Update-PageLayouts [-SiteCollectionURL] [-PageLayoutCurrent] [-PageLayoutNew] [-PageName (Page Name | All)] [-ApprovalState ( Publish | Approve )]

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can change the page layout that a page uses programmatically.

Refer to the [PublishingPage.Layout Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.publishingpage.layout.aspx)  on MSDN which includes a code sample.